# Why isn't soap used in baptism?

Tags: catholicism, baptism, sacraments, confirmation

Discussing the Waldensians' heresy "that no mixing of holy oil with water is permitted for receiving Baptism", Alfonso de Castro, O.F.M., in [*Against All Heresies*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=9173), § Baptism, quotes Thomas Netter (c. 1375 – 1430), *Doctrinale antiquitatum fidei Catholicae Ecclesiae: ad vetera exemplaria recognitum & notis illustratum* (1427) vol. 3, *De sacramentalibus* (Venice, Typis Antonii Bassanesii, 1757), c. 50, p. 328, regarding oil's signification:

> Athletes about to compete used to be anointed with fragrant and fortifying ointment, so that the slipperiness of those anointed would make them ungrippable, and unimpedible by the opponents: the smell sharpens the mind and consequently the senses, the absorption of it moistens the muscles and bones, it revives lifeless breathing, and thus strengthens the athlete.

This makes sense for the sacrament of confirmation, which is about strengthening a young Christian to be a soldier of Christ, but wouldn't soap be a better sign of the washing that happens in baptism?

Water and oil/anointing are mentioned in Holy Scriptures, but why not soap?

Comment: It appears that soap is mentioned at least twice, in Jeremiah 2:22 and in Malachi 3:2.

Comment: @Matthew "nitre" (_nitro_) and "fuller's herb" (_herba fullonum_), respectively, = soap?

Comment: Where are you getting those? Both verses use "בֹּרִ֑ית" ("bō·rîṯ")... although biblehub.com treats "וּכְבֹרִ֖ית" ("ū·ḵə·ḇō·rîṯ"; Malachi) as a different word. Consensus seems to be that this is some form or relative of [lye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lye).

Comment: @Matthew Vulgate translation

Comment: Ah, I wasn't looking at "נֶּ֔תֶר", which BTW also appears in Proverbs 25:20. "בֹּרִ֑ית" is also translated "herbam borith", suggesting that the translators may have believed it to refer to [soapwort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soapwort), which could explain why it's elsewhere translated "herba fullonum". In any case, the Hebrew root "bor" is translated as "cleanness" or "pureness", so it seems likely that "בֹּרִ֑ית" is, at least, used in some sense for cleaning.